# P value of R t.test() function

Tags: r, p-value

I understand that, the function `t.test` provides several statistical values, along with a `p-value`. However, I am not sure if this is a **one sided**, or **two sided** `p-value`.

Could someone tell me which `p-value` does it give as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?t.test` - my emphasis:

> alternative: a character string specifying the alternative hypothesis,
>             must be one of **'"two.sided"' (default)**, '"greater"' or
>             '"less"'.  You can specify just the initial letter.

Comment: +1 for politely indicating to the OP that they could have RTFM ...